# How to change data in dataset in R through custom function?

Tags: r

So I am using R and I want to change column values in my Pima Indian diabetes dataset but I cannot do so. I don't know what is going on:

```
#Duplicating dataset
pima_neural<-pima

#Max-Min Normalization function
normalize<-function(data,column){
  data[,column]<-data[,column]-min(data[,column])/max(data[,column])-min(data[,column])
  return(data[,column])
}



#Normalizing Pima columns
normalize(pima_neural,'Pregnancies')
```

Comment: First I would guess that you are missing some parentheses, it should probably be `(data[,column] - min(data[,column])) / (max(data[,column])-min(data[,column]))`. Second, your function will return a dataset with just one column. If you want to return the whole data then use `return(data)`

Answer (score 0):

With the help of stefan, I've gotten an answere. This is the correct code:

```
#Duplicating dataset
pima_neural<-pima

#Max-Min Normalization function
normalize<-function(data,column){
  data[,column]<-(data[,column] - min(data[,column])) / (max(data[,column])-min(data[,column]))
  return(data[,column])
}



#Normalizing Pima columns
pima_neural$Pregnancies<-normalize(pima_neural,'Pregnancies')
```